# Error adding new Peer in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, peer

To add a new peer in Hyperledger Fabric I am using following command

`peer = client.newPeer('grpcs://localhost:7051')`

getting following error

`PEM encoded certificate is required`

Please help!

Comment: I am unclear what you are trying to do. Can you please provide more context?

Comment: I was trying to run the middleware for Hyper Ledger Fabric locally, and new peer takes argument which we have to specify the TLS certificate name, worked out the name should be `PEM`. Thanks!

Comment: were you able to fix this issue. ? also what is your second argument

Comment: @rattanKunwar I have fixed this issue by including certificate file which is also called as `pem file`        `peer = client.newPeer('grpcs://localhost:7051', {pem:(path to your pem file)`}

Answer (score 0):

You can find PEM certificate in first-network folder and in connection-org1/org2.json.
Just start your network and after starting it copy the PEM certi.