# Error: PEM encoded certificate is required

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, peer

I am having this problem while connecting to fabric client using Node SDK. I refer to this [Error adding new Peer in Hyperledger Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204926/error-adding-new-peer-in-hyperledger-fabric) and I think this is also what I need to fix my problem. However I am confused as to what PEM file I should point it to. It will help if someone could provide a sample path of the PEM file. Thank you. Hope someone help.

Comment: facing this too.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you found a way back then, but here is the solution i found:

The PEM certificate you should point to is inside the crypto-config folder for the peer (i'm assuming you use cryptogen here, as stated in the fabric tutorial)

So the file should be located as such :

crypto-config/peerOrganizations/***PEER ORG NAME***/peers/***PEER NAME***/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.***PEER ORG NAME***-cert.pem

To be more complete, it seems that specifying the path to the certificate in the newPeer() call as stated in [the response you found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204926/error-adding-new-peer-in-hyperledger-fabric) doesn't cut it, since it needs the actual content of the file it this place.

So you will need to write the file content's there, by doing something like this:

```
      var channel = fabric_client.newChannel(channel);

      const fs = require('fs');
      let serverCert = fs.readFileSync('PATH_TO_PEM_CERT');
      var peer = fabric_client.newPeer(peerAddr, { pem :  Buffer.from(serverCert).toString() });

      channel.addPeer(peer);
```